# Process cannot Access a Locked File that is only used by my own Application

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I keep getting the following error when I try to write to a temporary file:

> The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Temp\jdoe.tmp' because it is being used
>   by another process.

These are the only methods that do anything with the file:

```
private void LoadData(string filePath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        File.Create(filePath);
        return;
    }

    var fileDetails = new FileInfo(filePath);
    if (fileDetails.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            // Do stuff...
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
}

private void SaveData(string filePath)
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        // Do stuff...
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

What is locking the file?

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that the calls to `Close()` within the `using` blocks aren't required.

Comment: @Alexei pointed that out in the answer and I did remove it from my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `File.Create(filePath)` returns a `FileStream`, which needs to be closed. The error disappeared by simply changing the `File.Create()` to this:

```
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    File.Create(filePath).Close();
    return;
}
```

Comment: It may be better to not call `Create` at all. Also you don't need `Close` inside `uisng` as it is redundant.

Answer (score -1):

you have to remove fist block of the code..

because when you will write .. if file is not there it will create the file or if file already there then it should append..

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please expand your answer some? It's not as expanded as it should be, please take a look at [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: Removing it causes `fileDetails.Length > 0` to fail but it works if I also add a `File.Exists(filePath)` check first.